# how to pass params from radio_button_tags to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is my form that displays all the `feedbacks` that was not reviewed yet by admin:

I have 2 radio buttons next to each `feedback` to select accept or denied with values `1` or `2`.

```
<% form_tag moderate_feedbacks_path, :method => :put do %>
  <table>
    <% @all_feedbacks.each do |feedback| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= radio_button_tag :review_option, '1', false, :name => feedback.id %></td>
      <td><%= radio_button_tag :review_option, '2', false, :name => feedback.id %></td>
      <td><%= feedback.name %></td>
      <td><%= feedback.email %></td>
      <td><%= feedback.message %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
   </table>
<%= submit_tag 'Apply' %>
<% end -%>
```

what I want to do is when I click `submit_tag`, to update the `review_option` field for each selected `feedback` with the value of that `radio_button_tag`, `1` or `2`

I have by now the form as you see it, works good, but I am stuck at the controller part:

```
def moderate_feedbacks
  Feedback.update_all(["review_option = ?", ????])
  redirect_to admin_feedbacks_path
end
```

how do I pass the params from those radio buttons to the controller.
Thank you.

**p.s.** html source:

```
<input id="review_option_1" name="3" type="radio" value="1">
<input id="review_option_2" name="3" type="radio" value="2">
```

name is taken from `feedback.id`

logs when I press the submit_tag looks like this;

```
Processing Admin::FeedbacksController#moderate_feedbacks (for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-16 15:36:20) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Apply", "3"=>"2", "4"=>"1"}
```

where 3 is the id of feedback - 2 the radio value, 4 is the id of feedback - 1 the radio value

after `raise.params["feedback.is"].inspect`

```
Parameters:

    {"commit"=>"Apply",
     "3"=>"1",
     "4"=>"1",
     "_method"=>"put"}
```

Comment: How does your params hash look? Can you paste your server log of your form submit? I think you have to pass the ids of the all feedback objects in your params, loop and update each feedback individually. This is a costly operation. I hope there would be better way of doing this.

Comment: thank you, I'll paste the view source of html file, cause this is an old rails 2.2 app and I run it with script/server not passenger.. so logs are hard to find.. I'll paste the html and I'll look for the logs right away

Comment: ok, added the logs, I hope this is the part you were looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so here is the answer:

in the **feedback.rb**

```
   class Status
     ACCEPTED = 1
     REJECTED = 2
   end
```

in the **form**:

```
<% form_tag moderate_feedbacks_path, :method => :put do %>
  <table>
    <% @all_feedbacks.each do |feedback| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= radio_button_tag :review_option, Feedback::Status::ACCEPTED, false, :name => feedback.id %></td>
      <td><%= radio_button_tag :review_option, Feedback::Status::REJECTED, false, :name => feedback.id %></td>
      <td><%= feedback.name %></td>
      <td><%= feedback.email %></td>
      <td><%= feedback.message %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
   </table>
<%= submit_tag 'Apply' %>
<% end -%>
```

in the **feedbacks_controller.rb**

```
   def moderate_feedbacks
    params.each do |key, value|
      if key =~ /^r(\d+)/ && !value.blank?
        feedback_id = $1
        Feedback.update_all(["review_option = ?", value.to_i], ["id = ?", feedback_id])
      end
    end
    redirect_to admin_feedbacks_path
  end
```

Comment: Upvoted for the assist on how to pass html options to form builder methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I'm not sure how the data is passed in params what I like to do is raise an exception in the controller.  The development exception handler outputs really great information about the contents of params.  I can even put in an .inspect for my exception and see the details.

```
def update
  raise "some string"
end
```

or

```
def update
  raise params["feedback.id"].inspect
end
```

Also note that the first argument to radio_button_tag is the name, so you do not have to pass it in the options.

Comment: did it your way and it returns   Parameters:{"commit"=>"Apply",
 "3"=>"1","4"=>"1","_method"=>"put"}  looks like parameters goes well.. anyway, the question is how so I write the code in the controller to take this params and save them in the table

Comment: if I don't pass the name in the option I can choose only one radio button from all the buttons I have, let's say I have 10 feedbacks and 2 buttons each, 20 radio buttons and I can select only one cause they have the same name, that's why I had to pass the name.

Comment: You didn't understand what I was saying.  The review_option argument is specifying the name as review_option.  If you call radio_button_tag twice with review_option, then both will have the name review_option.  Or you could pass feedback.id as the first argument of both radio_button_tag calls.

Comment: If the params variable is a hash where feedback.id is a key mapped to either "1" or "2", how do you access a hash to get the 1 or 2?

Comment: I posted the answer I got with the help from a friend of mine.. +1 for your help